# Confusion around the tikz-feynman package

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tikz-feynman

I know very little about LaTeX and TeX in general aside from how to actually write documents in it. I need to be able to make Feynman diagrams for a document I'm working on. However, when I use the `tikz-feynman` package I get weird configurations. For example for

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
```

I don't get the neat diagram as in the example [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/feynman_diagrams).
Instead I get a bunch of lines at weird angles. I have read that this happens when you use pdftex instead of luatex. However, I'm using LaTeX. Is it the case that LaTeX is either pdfTeX or LuaTeX? Or is it just not compatible with LaTeX in general? Anyone got any idea what could be the problem? If you need any further details please let me know. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Is this the same request that you have deleted before? To have that image you need of the packages.

Comment: Luatex here refers to the actual program you run to generate the PDF. In a command line you need to do `lualatex filename.tex` instead of `pdflatex filename.tex`, but you're probably running it from some editor, so to get more specific advice we'll need to know which editor that is.

Comment: @Sebastiano Hi, yes similar. However, I learned some things in the interim that required a complete restructure of the question so I thought a new question would be easier than trying to clarify the old one.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hi that's great thanks for the response. The editor I'm using is Atom, so I'm guessing Atom runs using pdflatex. If this is the case is there any way to make it run the feynman diagram excerpt in luatex?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to make Atom run lualatex, but having never used it, I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

I have read well the guide of `TikZ-Feynman` of the 2016 (I think a bit old) and if you see to the page 4 there is a reference of `LuaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`:

[image]

Using `MiKTeX 21.1 32-bit` on my laptop with the option it use `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (MiKTeX 21.1 32-bit)`,

[image]

and the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\), momentum'=\(k\)] b,
f1 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)],
};
\end{document}
```

works correctly.

[image]

The same for this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
a -- [photon] b,
f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

I remember that I use `TeXworks` a spartan editor.